# How to enable datastore admin

Tags: google-app-engine

When trying to access the datastore admin I get the following error message

```
2011-04-23 22:52:39.301

File referenced by handler not found: do_openid_login.py
```

Can you help? My app.yaml is

```
application: classifiedsmarket
version: tables
runtime: python
api_version: 1
default_expiration: "400d 5h"
handlers:
- url: /twitter
  script: /twitter_oauth_handler.py
- url: /oauth.*
  script: /twitter_oauth_handler.py
- url: /_ah/login_required
  script: do_openid_login.py
- url: /json
  script: main.py
- url: /
  script: i18n.py
- url: /li
  script: i18n.py
- url: /business
  script: i18n.py
- url: /blobthumbnailer
  script: i18n.py
- url: /login
  script: i18n.py
- url: /main.*
  script: i18n.py
- url: /ai.*
  script: i18n.py
- url: /facebook.*
  script: i18n.py
- url: /user.*
  script: i18n.py
- url: /_wave/.*
  script: classifiedsmarket.py
- url: /assets
  static_dir: assets
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
- url: /_
  static_dir: static
- url: /pay.*
  static_dir: pay
- url: /js.*
  script: javascript.py
- url: /step1.*
  script: step1.py
- url: /step2.*
  script: step2.py
- url: /onlinedebug.*
  script: onlinedebug/onlinedebug.py   
- url: /listfiles.*
  script: listfiles.py 
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
- url: /stylesheets/main.css
  static_files: stylesheets/main.css 
  upload: stylesheets/main.css 
- url: /stylesheets/facebook.css
  static_files: stylesheets/facebook.css 
  upload: stylesheets/facebook.css 
- url: /stylesheets/awesome-buttons.css
  static_files: stylesheets/awesome-buttons.css 
  upload: stylesheets/awesome-buttons.css 
- url: /stylesheets/a.css
  static_files: stylesheets/a.css 
  upload: stylesheets/a.css 
- url: /stylesheets/index.css
  static_files: stylesheets/index.css 
  upload: stylesheets/index.css 
- url: /stylesheets/1.css
  static_files: stylesheets/1.css 
  upload: stylesheets/1.css 
- url: /consume
  static_files: credit/credit.html 
  upload: credit/credit.html 
- url: /remote_api
  script: remote_api.py
  login: admin
  secure: never
- url: /robots.txt
  static_files: static/robots.txt
  upload: static/robots.txt
  secure: optional
  expiration: "24h" 
- url: /obrigado.txt
  static_files: static/obrigado.txt
  upload: static/obrigado.txt
  secure: optional
  expiration: "24h"
- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: static/favicon.ico
  upload: static/favicon.ico
- url: /googleb4b3b9748fe57cbf.html
  static_files: static/googleb4b3b9748fe57cbf.html
  upload: static/favicon.ico
- url: /(favicon\.ico)
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/.*
- url: /xd_receiver.htm
  static_files: static/xd_receiver.htm
  upload: static/xd_receiver.htm
- url: /_ah/mail/.+
  script: mailman.py 
  login: admin
- url: /rocket/.*
  script: rocket/rocket.py

# cron
- url: /report/daily
  script: reports.py
  login: admin
- url: /report/montaodaily
  script: reports.py
  login: admin
- url: /report/weekly
  script: reports.py
  login: admin

- url: /appengine_admin_media
  static_dir: appengine_admin/media
  secure: never
# All other URLs use main.py
- url: /.*
  script: main.py
inbound_services:
- xmpp_message
- mail
builtins:
- datastore_admin: on
- remote_api: on

error_handlers:
  - file: default_error.html
```

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you route .* to i18n.py, rather than having a dozen or so different routes for it?

Comment: I route .* to main.py and some other to i18n.py

Comment: What is the content of your do_openid_login.py file?

Comment: I don't have one. I believe I need to set one up but how do I do that? Is there documentation somewhere? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check  the "Authentication Options:"  in "Application Settings" in your application  console.
Change that to "Google Accounts API".

Comment: I had the same problem with my application deployed on Google App Engine / Java, and your solution worked. But I normally let users log in to my website with OpenId ("Federated Login" on GAE), so I could not really use this solution. I guess I will continue not to use the Datastore Admin!