# The Datastore Admin page is blank in my App Engine Control panel

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

The Datastore Admin page is blank in all my apps on appspot.com, I have followed the instructions to enable them, and receive no error message, just a blank page load.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Most of the appengine admin pages, in my experience, are somewhat delayed --- this is okay, because once the service or feature you have enabled comes on line, it will stay available....

Comment: I've waited for 5 mins or so, still not there?

Comment: Try a different browser.  
 DataStore Admin page didn't work for me on Safari but did work on Firefox.  
 However, this might be related to my Safari alternating between 2 different google accounts as mentioned by Can below.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you are on Google Chrome and logged in via multiple gmail accounts, try to open up App Engine dashboard using an incognito window. That should solve it.

Comment: Ah, will try this, sounds promising!

Comment: @ChrisBarry OMW! How on earth did u figure that out? Worked for me, thanks- Vote + 1

Comment: @BabajidePrince It's not that hard to figure out really. An incognito window works with no cookies. Therefore, no sessions can be established with the server. Therefore, from Googles perspective, you are an anonymous user. When you re-logged in you are doing so with the 1 account you want to use, so google cannot get 'confused' about who you are.

Comment: oops, Yes did vote him up..  @gwynhowell I disagree with u, U spend time to develop ur app and all u wana do on the Console now is administer ur app, what does that have to do with u figuring out how Google sees u as a user? No direct link. We only talking about cookies, anonymous user etc because we now know that it has to do with Authentication. If you see a blank screen only when you go to Datastore admin, how can you tell it has to do with authentication when other links work well? I'll disagree with u till kingdom come!

Answer (score 27):

For future users with same **blank page problem and Federated login** you can also try the following.

Try to open the Datastore Admin page and if it's black then view the page source.

Your should see something like this (chrome - firefox - safari):

```
<iframe style="border:0px solid #ffffff"
        frameborder="0"
        src="https://ah-builtin-python-bundle-dot-latest-dot-app-id.appspot.com/_ah/datastore_admin/?app_id=s~app-id&adminconsolecustompage"
        width="100%"
        height="1024px">
<p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

The link you are looking for is the src:

```
https://ah-builtin-python-bundle-dot-latest-dot-app-id.appspot.com/_ah/datastore_admin/?app_id=s~app-id&adminconsolecustompage
```

Copy the link with the datastore admin login auth and open it in a new window.

That will ask you from OpenID(GOOGLE) to confirm that you want to grant access to Datastore admin to your email etc.

**Allow and done ;-)**

PS. This works once and you don't have to re do it again. Though you have to follow the same procedure for **each** of your apps that you have enabled **Federated login**

Comment: This did the trick for me. Top solution (incognito) does not work for federated login. Thx!

Answer (score 4):

It might also be because you are using Federated Login. I had the same issues with blank screens and no error messages. For me, the Datastore Admin became available when I changed the Authentications Options back to Google Accounts API. Definitely not a permanent solution, but desperate times calls for desperate solutions.

Ref: [How to enable datastore admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5768921/how-to-enable-datastore-admin)

Comment: Also for federated login I found a workarround that posted in following answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open your browser's dev tools and look for errors in the console. In Firefox, I received:

   Invalid 'X-Frame-Options' header encountered when loading 'https://ah-builtin-python-bundle-dot-healthometry-hrd.appspot.com/_ah/datastore_admin/?app_id=s~healthometry-hrd&adminconsolecustompage': 'ALLOW-FROM https://appengine.google.com' is not a recognized directive. The header will be ignored.
2. Open the long link in a separate tab and go through the federated login process. The datastore admin will appear. Upon refreshing your appengine.google.com page the Datastore Admin should appear there as well.