# Google App Engine - Link for Datastore Admin gives Error: Not Found

Tags: google-app-engine

In Google App Engine when I click on `Datastore Admin` for an application I get an error like this (where APPID is my application ID):

> Error: Not Found
>
> The requested URL /_ah/login_required?continue=https://ah-builtin-python-bundle-dot-latest-dot-APPID.appspot.com/_ah/datastore_admin/?app_id=s~APPID was not found on this server.

A Google search did not turn up anything useful. Has anyone else encountered this problem or know of potential solutions?

Comment: Is is this [issue](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=5864)?

Comment: @user1158367: It is. Federated Login. Thanks.

Comment: The comment from Yohann answers it.

Comment: I hit the same issue for one of my apps while trying to go to an admin role url. It appears somehow that app was using authentication type "Federated Login" vs. "Google Accounts Api" (as indicated by Yohann). Very un-intuitive. I switched it back to "Google Accounts Api" and was able to login.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The Datastore Admin page is blank in my App Engine Control panel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8280623/the-datastore-admin-page-is-blank-in-my-app-engine-control-panel)

Comment: Happy to close as dupe